# Groovy & IntelliJ: how to extract variable with explicit type declaration?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, refactoring

How to extract variable (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) in Groovy in IntelliJ to get this:

```
Car car = new Car()
```

instead of this?

```
def car = new Car()
```

Comment: Yeeee, someone also prefers explicit typing

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> on `def` and choose type. Next time Intellij will use specified type.

Comment: Shift + Tab shifts whole line to left. Any idea what else can work? Plus do you know whether is it possible to make compilation in inttelij of groovy classses better? He does not highlight syntax errors at all. For instance I can write SomeType a = SomeType() (missing new keyword) and it reports no errors.

Comment: You have to use Shift + Tab while you're extracting variable (`def` is highlighted).

If Intellij does not highlight groovy syntax make sure you have sources marked as groovy sources.

Comment: works as a charm. Thanks! Any idea how to force intellij compile time checkes on groovy code? Or is it impossible because of dynamic character of groovy?

Comment: 4 years later and this is still useful! Great answer! :)